# Store output after finding matching string using regex and pexpect

Tags: python, regex, parsing, regex-lookarounds, pexpect

I'm writing a Python script and I am having some trouble figuring out how to get the output of a command I send and store it in a variable, but for the entire output of that command - I only want to store the rest of 1 specific line after a certain word.

To illustrate - say I have a command that outputs hundreds of lines that all represent certain details of a specific product.

```
Color: Maroon Red
Height: 187cm
Number Of Seats: 6
Number Of Wheels: 4
Material: Aluminum
Brand: Toyota 
#and hundreds of more lines...
```

I want to parse the entire output of the command that I sent which print the details above and only store the material of the product in a variable.

Right now I have something like:

```
child.sendline('some command that lists details')
variable = child.expect(["Material: .*"])
print(variable)
child.expect(prompt)
```

The sendline and expect prompt parts list the details correctly and all, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to parse the output of that command, look for a part that says "Material: " and only store the Aluminum string in a variable.

So instead of having variable equal to and print a value of 0 which is what currently prints right now, it should instead print the word "Aluminum".

Is there a way to do this using regex? I'm trying to get used to using regex expressions so I would prefer a solution using that but if not, I'd still appreciate any help! I'm also editing my code in vim and using linux if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to look for the substring `Material:` . For this you can place the string you want to match (I am using a dot character, which means "match any character") in between a positive lookbehind for `Material:`  and a positive lookahead for `\r\n`:

```
(?<=Material:\s).*(?=[\r\n])
```

You can find a good explanation for this regex [here](https://regex101.com/r/ZSr2Ud/1).

Comment: Hello, thank you for your help! How would I store this output in a variable though? Would it be like var = exp.expect((?<=Material:\s).*(?=[\r\n])) or something?

Comment: What exactly do you want to store? Is it the matched string or something else?

Comment: The matched string. I'm trying to figure out how to store "Aluminum" in a variable

Comment: Use `x = re.search(regex, string)`. This will store "Aluminum" in `x`.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using Python, you can use a capture group and store the value in for example `my_var` in the example code.

```
^Material:\s*(.+)
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `Material:\s*` Match `Material:` and optional whitspace chars
- `(.+)` Capture **group 1** match 1+ times any char except a newline

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/opZAjG/1) and a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/eBHDZ7).

For example

```
import re

regex = r"^Material:\s*(.+)"

s = ("Color: Maroon Red\n"
            "Height: 187cm\n"
            "Number Of Seats: 6\n"
            "Number Of Wheels: 4\n"
            "Material: Aluminum\n"
            "Brand: Toyota \n"
            "#and hundreds of more lines...")

match = re.search(regex, s, re.MULTILINE)
if match:
    my_var = match.group(1)
    print(my_var)
```

Output

```
Aluminum
```

Comment: Hello - I noticed you copied and pasted the output into the variable s. Is there a way to just automatically grab and store the entire output of the command without copying and pasting it into s? The output may change sometimes and it's also a lot of lines

Comment: @rickymorty101 You can use a lookbehind `(?<=^Material:\s).+` to get the value only, but it is less efficient than a capture group. You still need to get the value from re.seach, and as re.search could return `None` you would have to check for it.